# Options to do regarding a hacked twitch stream with a known twitter, used email and (maybe fake) name

Tags: vpn

In short, a friend of mine under DzyDzyDino's stream.

I contacted him and together we were able to obtain a bit of information. First, though, the overall situation.

I managed to contact him via phone, but it turns out that everything was compromised. Twitch, twitter, and skype were all attacked. I tried to contact him via skype, and all that happened was a twitter was given of the "hacker". It seems they were a bit careless, though.

During this time, I had donated to twitch, and instead of the usual email, I retrieved the Alias the person uses (possibly the real name), and a few other bits of information. Clearly he didn't want me to contact him, because my internet went out for a reasonable amount of time. (It took a few cmd commands to get it back).

Hacking Group: https://twitter.com/skidgriefinq 
Group owner: https://twitter.com/zSyntaxii

According to my email receipt from a paypal donation, the money was sent to superhaystack2@gmail.com

By removing the 2, I managed to get a name: Hayden Baahston, and a facebook with the same email implying that he is some sort of kid

He also claimed to be using a VPN. While these aren't untraceable, we know it makes it harder to get a location.

In short, what are our options? I've already given him the run down of needed to redo all of his skype contacts, ect, change passwords, and so forth.

Comment: But if online accounts are compromised the legitimate owner should contact the companies that provide the account's services and provide them as much personal info and an overview of what happened to convince them to give the accounts back to him. Do this on a clean machine to rule out any malware issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option is to have your friend scan his computer for malware, and contact twitch support. They will probably eventually help your friend recover their account. Your friend might also want to consider adding phone verification to his twitter and twitch account.

Also, you can report the hacker's account to paypal.